# Java spellchecking with autocompletion

Tags: java, autocomplete, spell-checking

I've added spell checking to a spreadsheet-like program used at our company using Jazzy. It seems to be working well for the usual complete words with typos. There's a case it doesn't handle well at all though, which is also fairly common in the data we work with: truncated words.

Initially I thought maybe the word list was incomplete, but then I realized that it's doing a "sounds-like" style comparison of whole words. Is there any way to get auto-complete spelling suggestions along with the regular suggestions?

It'd be nice if I could stick with Jazzy but it's an important enough feature for us that I'll start over with something else if that's what's required. I've found a fair amount of info about autocomplete with Solr but it doesn't look like that would be a good fit in the context of a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Solr is based on Lucene which is a library and can thus nicely be integrated into a desktop app. [PrefixQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html) can be used for fast auto-completion.